# How to style a pie chart in chart js? I want to change the border color, border width and give them shadow

Tags: chart.js

**Here is my HTML div:**

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="290" height="140"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = $("#mycanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");    
  var data = [{
      value: 923864,
      color: "#58508d",
      highlight: "#003f5c",
      label: "Dr. John",
    },
    {
      value: 720988,
      color: "#3292b0",
      highlight: "#6fefff",
      label: "Alex"
    },
    {
      value: 179539,
      color: "orange",
      highlight: "darkblue",
      label: "Other",
    },
  ];
  var piechart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First at all, you should upgrade to the most stable version of Chart.js, which currently is v2.9.4.

The `dataset` accepts number of [properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#dataset-properties), that can be defined for styling the border. Its color and width are controlled through the following ones.

- `borderColor` arc border color
- `borderWidth` arc border width (in pixels).

In order to see a shadow, you can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. In the `beforeDraw` for example, you can draw a circle with shadow through [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.arc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc).

Please take a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'pie',
  plugins: [{
    beforeDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
      ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = -10;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      const x = chart.chart.width / 2;
      const y = chart.chart.height / 2 + 15;
      ctx.arc(x, y, 95, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['Dr. John', 'Alex', 'Other'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [923864, 720988, 179539],
      backgroundColor: ['#58508d', '#3292b0', 'orange'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['#003f5c', '#6fefff', 'darkblue'],
      borderWidth: 0
    }],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 15,
        bottom: 20
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="260"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Looks like the newer version is not for download anymore, one needs to download it's whole GitHub repository  or link its CDN version?? I didn't find chart.js file in their repository to copy and paste it into my local machine, unless I link its live version as you did here.

Comment: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/download/v2.9.4/chart.js-2.9.4.tgz (365 KB)